# How do I find Github File_ID?

Tags: github, github-pages, github-api

I have created a new repository on github and uploaded a test index.html file on it . How can I find the File_ID for this file ?

Should be something like : File_ID=765345_index.html

I was able to get User_ID via api at https://api.github.com/ but I have no idea what to do for File_ID .